# My video player for flash was replaced. What player is it and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: video, flash

This is what I see instead of every flash video in the web, both in firefox and chromium. 
Non-functional. Previously I installed minitube and Unity 5, both now removed.

[image]

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: please react to responses mate ! you should follow shantanu response and react. use flashplugin-installer from synaptic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove totem-mozilla plugin

```
sudo apt-get remove totem-mozilla
```

Install adobe plugin

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Stop all your web browser first before install.